# whenever delete the record from sqlite databse navigate the activity to previous and display the records which available in databse

Tags: android

In my application listview is available and in each row add button and show button available, whenever add button clicked the data is stored sqlite database.After show button clicked navigate the another activity in that all data displayed which is available in database. And in that activity delete button is available,whenever delete button is clicked delete the record from the database at the same time navigate the activity to previous activity and display remaining records in that activity.And my question is how to navigate activity after delete the record from the database.
This is my onclick listener
 if(v.equals(btnAddBeer)){

```
            if(addCheck==true){
              if(helper.getBeerid(strBeerId).getCount()>0)
              {
```

//                  Toast.makeText(MyBeersActivity.this, "Already added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                  else{

```
               db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
               helper.insert(strBeerId,strBeerName,strBeerId,db);
               btnAddBeer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deletebeer_reviews);
               Toast.makeText(MyBeersReviewsActivity.this, "Successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               addCheck=false;
              }
            }
            else{



                helper.deleteRecord(strBeerId);
                Log.e("delete.....","successfully");

                new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent()) 
                .setTitle("Message")
                .setMessage(strBeerName+" is deleted successfully")
                .setPositiveButton(DataUrls.dialogbutton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                            {
                                MyBeersTabActivity.group.onBackPressed();
                            }
                }).show();
            }
        }
```

1. List item

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply need to `finish()` the "data display" `Activity` from the OnClickListener of the delete button.

Comment: my question is how to navigate to previous screen and how to retrieve the records available in database.In which method i have to write the code to retrieve the records.

Comment: Typically you'd do this in the `onResume()` method of your list activity.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong :). You post no code, you provide general questions, I provide general answers. Refresh your `CursorAdapter` in `onResume()`, that's the _typical_ strategy.

Comment: I am cheking but onresume metod also called at first time

Comment: onresume method is not executed

Answer (score 0):

You can go back to the previous page using onBackPressed() function.Call this inbuilt function in your onclick event of the delete button.